# How to convert Sqlite.swift Binding to a primitive Swift type?

Tags: swift, sqlite.swift

How can I get a primitive Swift type from a SQLite.swift Binding, I have this sample:

```swift
            for row in try db.prepare("select * from table") {
                let t = row[0]! as Int64
```

It shows me an error `'any Binding' is not convertible to 'Int64'`

Comment: Try to move the exclamation mark to after `as`